# Cassandra generates “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error on startup

Tags: java, cassandra, out-of-memory, cassandra-2.0

I upgraded my system from 13.04 to 13.10 and I could not start Cassandra anymore, getting an out of memory error, so the heap was getting full even though all I was doing at that point was start the server.

I went in and increased the maximum heap size with -Xmx1992m (the default) to -Xms2500m.

I am wondering why would it be required to do such a thing? Could it be that the memory decreased a little bit between running Linux kernel 3.5.0 and moving to kernel 3.11.0 and could that impact Cassandra? (i.e. say I "lost" 200M, now it was allocating 1992Mb instead of 2192Mb with the previous kernel, could that be??)

My concern here is that any time I upgrade I could run in a problem like this unless I force the maximum heap size to a fixed number (instead of letting the script determine the Mb to use dynamically.) Plus, I just cannot continue to increase the limit forever. My RAM is limited... (obviously.)

On startup Cassandra shows the following (broken on 3 lines to make it easier to read here):

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities
       -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1994M -Xmx2500M -Xmn400M
       -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
```

---

Update:

Argh! It was still starting OpenVMS because the $JAVA_HOME variable that points to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java (it is defined in /etc/environment):

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

And somehow it was setup back to OpenVMS in there. Although I changed the /etc/alternatives/java softlink, and thus `java -version` in my command line was "working fine" (returning what I'd expect) the Cassandra startup script makes use of the `$JAVA_HOME` variable!

So I checked the list of available VMs with:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Apr 27  2012 default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 23 17:54 java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Sep  2  2012 java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-6-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul  3  2013 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct  7  2012 java-6-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct  7  2012 java-6-openjdk-common
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep 21 20:06 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Sep 18 21:18 java-7-oracle
```

And ran the following two commands to get Oracle to run:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
sudo ln -s java-7-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

However, that did **not** change the fact that I still need to have a large upper limit in terms of memory.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit jvm?

Comment: Oh! I wanted to put the info with parameters and such. I am on 64bit. Using Oracle, although it was set on OpenJVM when I rebooted and did not notice until after I tested so it tried several times with OpenJVM. Both version 7.

Comment: Oh! I changed the alternative to Oracle, but it looks like that's not enough. It makes use of `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java` and it looks like that would be OpenJVM. Arrrgh!

Comment: So how much memory does a simple Java test program report available?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, No idea. I don't write Java code. The -Xms and -Xmx define the available heap to the software. I find it really difficult to understand Cassandra, in part because I do not use Java myself and thus a lot of things are really not clear in that respect alone.

Comment: Your way of setting the default java version is not right.  I would suggest you have a look on http://askubuntu.com on how to do it.  Also be sure that you are running a 64 bit JVM.  Openjdk should be fine for your purposes.

Comment: The package managing that softlink is default-jre-headless which does not come with any script or binaries. I'm not too sure how you're supposed to change that link. See answer by Mahesh here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/181381/what-package-creates-usr-lib-jvm-default-java

Answer (score 2):

Things like the memory usage of applications, libraries, and even core Java are subject to change without notice. You should expect particularly massive changes to be documented but in most cases a few hundred MB here or there will not be.

It's a general truism that in most cases memory usage increases as software develops. As programs get bigger, get more features, etc then they also consume more memory. The only way to see how much memory you will need for a particular piece of software doing a particular job is to test it - and if the software version changes test it again.

The easiest way is just to make sure you allocate enough headroom in the first place that small increases will not be a problem.

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately at times it also means things stop working, which is a real annoyance. For example, at this point I have no sound at all. It used to work since I got the computer like 4 or 5 years ago. A shame really.